# Is there a word similar to infallible that means "incapable of being right"?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary, antonyms

The word *infallible* can mean "incapable of being wrong".

The word *fallible* can mean "capable of being wrong".

Is there a word that means "incapable of being right"?

Comment: Calling them "infallibly wrong" ought to do the trick, if you can use two words.

Answer (score 2):

**Schlemiel** In Yiddish/American slang, a dopey, awkward person--a person who never gets any good luck and who is not particularly graceful The word 'schlemiel' means 'chronic bungler' in Yiddish (from a character in a classic German fable by A. von Chamissa (1781-1838) The fable,'The Wonderful History of Peter Schlemihl' appeared in 1813.

Answer (score 1):

"Incorrigible" means incapable of being corrected, which is close.

Answer (score 0):

"clueless" comes close. Although it also connotes total oblivious ignorance of a topic, someone who is clueless would never get the right answer.

Or, you could say "He's a veritable Fox News host when it comes to [x]"